# Creating an array of subarrays by slicing a bigger array into chunks (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, split

I am trying to make a method that given an array and k (number of subarrays we want to divide it into), it will divide the said array into that number of subarrays. I made this so far:

```
   public static int[][] slice(int[] arr, int k) {
     int i, j;
     int arrLength = arr.length;
     double divided = arrLength / k;
     int evenOdd = arrLength % k;
     int chunks = (int) Math.ceil((double) arrLength / k);

     int[][] output = IntStream.iterate(0, l -> l + chunks)
       .limit((int) Math.ceil((double) arr.length / chunks))
       .mapToObj(m -> Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, m, Math.min(arr.length, m + chunks)))
       .toArray(int[][]::new);

     return output;
   }
```

However, this only works when the variable k is smaller or equal to half the size of the array we give. For example, if I give the arr {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} and choose k=5, it still separates my array into 4 subarrays.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks very much in advance.